# ¿Es posible agrandar un <div> pellizcándole en Chrome para Android?

Tags: android, imagen, chrome

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web y deseo agrandar objetos pellizcando bien sea para agrandar como disminuir el tamaño.
El objeto estaría en un div y este a su vez dentro de otro div que serviría de lienzo o base

Ejemplo

```
<div id="lienzo"><img id="objeto" src="objeto.png" /></div>
```

Lo que deseo es agrandar el tamaño de la imagen "objeto". Todo esto en el navegador chrome de en un dispositivo Android